# sum of elements at an even index in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sum

I have this code in order to sum elements at an even index in array..

I was wondering why if i'm writing:
`for(i=1; i<size; i+2)` it doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6

int func (int* arr, int size)
{
    int i;
    int j=2;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)  //why not for (i=1; i<size; i+2) ??????????
            sum+=arr[i];
    return sum;
} 

void main()
{
    int arr[SIZE]= {1,2,3,1,4,1};
    printf ("%d", func (arr,SIZE));

}
```

thank you

Comment: `i+2` => `i+=2`. `i+2` doesn't change `i`

Comment: Uh, "even elements" is not the same as "elements at an even index". This is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i + 2` does not change the value of `i`. You can either use `i += 2`, or `i = i+2`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6

int func (int* arr, int size)
{
    int i;
    int j=2;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i+=2) // now works since i is being modified.
        sum+=arr[i];

    return sum;
} 

void main()
{
    int arr[SIZE]= {1,2,3,1,4,1};
    printf ("%d", func (arr,SIZE));
}
```

Comment: There is another problem when `size` is odd due to out-of-bounds access. Changing `i<size` to `i<=size-2` will fix it.